# How to count number of semicolon in the Textbox field In Infopath 2013?

Tags: infopath

```
Field A Value Is : Test1;Test2;Test3;Test4
```

I need to count number of semicolon present in Field A Like : 3

its possible to do this without coding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Field A: Test1;Test2;Test3;Test4

Field B(default value):
 `string-length(translate(FieldA, "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", ""))`

Result: 3

Translate function is to convert the other characters to blank(no space) and then using string-length to count the semicolons that are left.

EDIT:
Created a blog [post](http://mekalikot.blogspot.com/2015/08/count-number-of-specific-character-in-string-infopath.html) for this one for detailed explanation and steps.

Comment: Don't forget to add special characters if you expect them to be in your field text

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string-length(FieldA) - string-length(translate(FieldA, ";", ""))
```

Result: 3